# Gradle merging multiple web projects for eclipse workspace by Buildship

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, war, buildship

I am in the middle of migrating existing legacy project to Gradle.

It has several web projects to merge into a final WAR file.

in the build.gradle file of the integrated web project:

```
configurations {
    webProj1 
    webProj2 
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        compileClasspath += configurations.webProj1 
        compileClasspath += configurations.webProj2


        java {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'resources'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    webProj1  project(':webProj1')
    webProj2  project(':webProj2')

}

war{
    from(webProjDirPath1 + '/WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp'){  
         into 'jsp'
    }

    from(webProjDirPath2 + '/WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp'){  
         into 'jsp'
    }

    ....
}
```

Now I am trying to make the local workspace war file building to work. Is there a way to make the gradle buildship plugin to recognize this merging and generate relevant settings for eclipse ?